# Best data store solution for small mathematical data but fast and with aggregate functions

Tags: database, nosql, cloud, storage, distributed-system

I'm looking for a data storage solution for a project with these requirements:

1. The application creates dynamically
   a containter/table in the store.
2. For a small period of time (two
   weeks for example) that
   table/container gets a huge amount
   of inserts in parallel. Last read
   have to be immediately available.
3. The data inserted is very small, 4
   to 6 numeric columns.
4. Small query/filtering support is
   required, but no joins or cross
   queries.
5. Is needed to execute some aggregate
   functions like "Count", "Sum",
   "Max", "Min" and "Avg".

Basically, I need something like Windows Azure Table Storage but with aggregate functions.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RavenDB](http://ravendb.net) supports all you mentioned and more. Its scales very well, and supports aggregate functions via Map/Reduce queries and Linq queries. It also can run in-memory.

Answer (score 3):

[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) is also a good choice. It supports group (aggregate) queries on single-node installation. If you need to scale you can create sharded cluster and use map/reduce for aggregation needs - but Mongo map/reduce performance isn't top level when comapring to other solutions.

If you need big performance in map/reduce you can take look at [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use **SQL Azure**? It support Aggregate function and meet all of your needs, take a look at [this table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336248.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If it does not have to be free, kdb+ would be a good choice.  It is a system mainly uses in finance for time series analysis. It supports everything you ask for and is incredibly fast.  There is a free trial version available, but to use it in production it is...expensive. It is fully queryable with a sql-like syntax and fully programmable with a proprietary language called q which is in the apl family.

http://www.kx.com/

Answer (score 0):

For the requirements listed in the question body, any competent SQL server on the market would handle this, altho you would need to set up some indexes to get things to be super fast.

But that's like saying, if you want your car to go fast, you have to put it in D and press the gas pedal, so that's that fwiw.

Answer (score 0):

Really need more info on the requirements and budget... but, since people are just throwing up some answers, I'll throw this one into the mix:

There are some very cool, and very expensive, hardware solutions built to run massively parallel SQL queries, such as the Netezza Skimmer or TwinFin

http://www.netezza.com/data-warehouse-appliance-products/skimmer.aspx

Almost makes me wish our data warehouse was too slow - just so I could get one of these puppies.